# Не отображается slider slick в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Такая проблема. Я натягиваю страницу на wordpress. По каким то причинам у меня ВООБЩЕ не отображается слайдер slick. При этом код есть и даже показывает значок якобы есть, но сам слайдер как будто стал невидимым. Буду очень рада за помощь!

P.s теги php я не добавила, но ни есть.

Файл index.php

```html
   <?php get_header(); ?>
    <!-- Content site -->
    <!-- Main slider -->
    <content class = "background_content">
        
        <!-- men's clothing carousel -->
        <div class="osnovaniye">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/slide_man_1.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/slide_man_2.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/slide_man_3.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/slide_man_1.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/slide_man_2.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/slide_man_3.png" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- women's clothing carousel -->
        <div class="osnovaniye_1">
            <div class="slider_1">
                <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_1.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_2.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_3.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_1.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_2.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_3.png" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- men's clothing carousel (320px) -->
        <div class = "scroll-slider">
            <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_1.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_2.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_3.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="assets/img/slide_man_1.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="assets/img/slide_man_2.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda"><img src="assets/img/slide_man_3.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <!-- women's clothing carousel (320px) -->
        <div class = "scroll-slider_1">
            <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_1.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_2.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_wom_3.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_man_1.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_man_2.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="moving_slayda_1"><img src="assets/img/slide_man_3.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </content>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Файл functions.php

```html
// правильный способ подключить стили и скрипты
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'clothing_store_scripts' );
// add_action('wp_print_styles', 'theme_name_scripts'); // можно использовать этот хук он более поздний
function clothing_store_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-clothing_store', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-clothing_store', get_template_directory_uri() . 'slider.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-bootstrap.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/bootstrap.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-bootstrap.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-jquery.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-slick.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/slick.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-html5.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/html5shiv.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-resp.js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/respond.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );


    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-boot_min_css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-font-awesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-popper_min_js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-boot_min_js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-jquery_min_js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-slick_min_js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js' );


}
```

Файл style.css

```css
    /* carousel of men's goods */
    .osnovaniye {
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .slick-slider {
    min-width: 0;
    }
    .slick-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slick-track {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .slider {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 60px;
    left: 45px;
    top: 205px;
    }
    .slider .slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    }
    .slider .slick-arrow.slick-prev {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("assets/img/strelka_prev.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: 215px;
    width: 54px;
    height: 85px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    }
    .slider .slick-arrow.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("assets/img/strelka_next.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 1570px;
    top: 215px;
    width: 54px;
    height: 85px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    }
    .slider .slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    .moving_slayda {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    .moving_slayda img {
    width: 391px;
    height: 477px;
    }

    /* carousel of women's goods */
    .osnovaniye_1 {
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .osnovaniye_1 {
    padding: 50px 10px;
    }
    }
    .slick-slider {
    min-width: 0;
    }
    .slick-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slick-track {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .slider_1 {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 60px;
    left: 45px;
    top: 475px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .slider_1 {
    padding: 0px 40px;
    }
    }
    .slider_1 .slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    }
    .slider_1 .slick-arrow.slick-prev {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("assets/img/strelka_prev.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: 215px;
    width: 54px;
    height: 85px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none; 
    }
    .slider_1 .slick-arrow.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("assets/img/strelka_next.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 1570px;
    top: 215px;
    width: 54px;
    height: 85px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    }
    .slider_1 .slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    .moving_slayda_1 {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    .moving_slayda_1 img {
    width: 391px;
    height: 477px;
    }
    .sub{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 740px;
    top: 670px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    }
    .scroll-slider{
    display:none;
    }
    .moving_slayda{
    display: none;
    }
    .scroll-slider_1{
    display: none;
    }
    .moving_slayda_1{
    display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоли? Вообще обычно когда используете `wp_enqueue_script();` должен быть слеш, перед директорией, в данном случае перед bootstrap: `get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/slick.min.js'`. Но Вы так же зачем-то продублировали эти скрипты из cdn.

Comment: Поставила, все равно ничего не происходит

Comment: Тоже самое нужно и со `slider.js` сделать, но я вообще не говорил что проблема именно в этом. Это может быть связано и с самим JS и PHP кодом. И Вы уверены что Ваш слайдер должен быть именно в `index.php`?